# ckeck if user like Facebook page or not without request Access Token

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '********', // App ID
          channelUrl : document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js', // Channel File
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });


 var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = "+page_id+"and uid="+user_id;
            FB.Data.query(fql_query).wait(function(rows) {
              if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
                console.log("LIKE");
                $('#container_like').show();
              } else {
                console.log("NO LIKEY");
                $('#container_notlike').show();
              }             }
```

just  i need to check   user  like Facebook page or  not  with out  request any  access token  or permission  is that possible  ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes , i possible  i did  that  by  php with following code  with out request  and permission from user

```
        require 'src/facebook.php';
// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
        $facebook = new Facebook( array(
            'appId' => '***************',
            'secret' => '**********************',
            'cookie' => true,
                ) );
        $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
// Return you the Page like status
        $like_status = $signed_request[ "page" ][ "liked" ];

        if ( $like_status ) {?>
            <div class="facebook-data-content" id="facebook-data-content"> </div>

        <?php } else {
            ?>
            <div class="like-gate" id="like-gate"> </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

and  you can  do   the same  with JavaScript 
  note : all need check that redirect URL  correct  first before do anything because most problem  about this issues

good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it's possible if I'm understanding you correctly...   ultimately youre always going to need the user to authorize your app and get an auth token in order to know the user's id. FB doesnt let you know user's uid without their permission